# Connecting More Than Six Analog Input Pins to arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, input

I'm in the planning stages for a project using the Arduino Uno to control 8 distance sensors, and have run into a little road block, the Uno only has six input pins. So I'm wondering, is there any way for this to work? If so, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it ([TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)).

There are a several ways to connect 8 analog inputs to an Arduino.

- Add an analog multiplexer, as georgebrindeiro suggested. Such as: [(a)](http://shieldlist.org/appliedplatonics/analoginput), [(b)](http://shieldlist.org/mayhewlabs/mux), [(c)](http://shieldlist.org/criticalvelocity/monstermux), [(d)](http://blueberryde.com/shop/24-channel-analog-expander-shield/), etc.
- Replace the Arduino with one that has enough analog inputs already built-in. Such as the Arduino Mini with 8 analog inputs, the Arduino Due with 12 analog inputs [(b)](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue), [(a)](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMini) the Arduino Mega with 16 analog inputs [(b)](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega), the Teensy 3.0 with 14 analog inputs [(c)](http://forum.jeelabs.net/node/1429.html), etc.
- Add one or more external ADCs, and connect it to digital pins of your CPU. Such as: Arduino 4-20mA Shield with 16-bit ADC [(a)](http://erdosmiller.com/products/arduino-4-20ma-shield); ADS1115 16-Bit ADC -- with 4 of these boards, 2 digital pins from the Arduino are used to read 16 analog inputs [(b)](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts); MCP3208 8 channel 12 bit SPI ADC [(c)](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,18827.0.html); 8-channel 16-bit Raspi analog board [(d)](http://hackaday.com/2012/09/14/a-truly-professional-raspi-analog-input/); Arduino and the LTC2440 24bit ADC [(e)](http://blog.arduino.cc/2012/07/11/arduino-and-the-ltc2440-24bit-adc/) [(f)](http://blog.arduino.cc/2010/11/29/tired-of-a-10-bit-res-hook-up-a-better-analog-to-digital-converter/); "The Brick" 8 Single Ended 16 Bit Analog Inputs [(g)](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=69358.0); etc.

p.s.: Multiplexing analog inputs requires an "analog multiplexer" -- most multiplexers are "digital muxes" which won't work with analog inputs.

p.p.s.:
All the ultrasonic distance sensors I've used only require digital I/O pins.
What kind of distance sensors are you using?

Comment: Of course! your right, they only need i/o, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you have more signals than appropriate inputs in a digital system, you likely need a multiplexer or simply mux. An M-to-N mux is a circuit that enables you to select which of M input signals you want to output to N mux outputs, usually using digital pins to make that selection.

Googling quickly, I found this solution for the Arduino Uno: a [Mux Shield](http://mayhewlabs.com/products/mux-shield-2). Hope that helps!